# Leer archivo csv y borrarle contenido en C

Tags: c, archivo

ayer me ayudaron a leer un archivo csv y quitarle comas (GRACIAS) ahora me han pedido que se le pueda borrar contenido a dicho archivo, nos comentaron que se podía cargar el contenido en un arreglo y de ahí poder borrar los datos y rehacer el archivo pero la verdad es que no tengo idea de como hacer esto... :/

```
//1) Funcion Mostrar
void fumos(){

    char opbackin[100]={};
    int c=0;

    FILE*lista_alumnos;
    lista_alumnos=fopen("lista_alumnos.csv","r");

    system("cls"); //Windows

    printf("Mostrar lista de alumnos del 1CV2\n\n\n\n");

    if(lista_alumnos==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error al abrir el fichero\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while((c = fgetc(lista_alumnos)) != EOF)
        {
            if (c == '\n')
            printf("\n");
            printf("%c", ((c == ',') ? ' ' : c));
        }
    }

    return;
    }
```

este el código de la función que lee el archivo, por favor si tienen una idea de como hacer que se le pueda borrar contenido se los agradecería.

Adjunto el archivo por si les es de utilidad en este [enlace](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvbESCUHvMH2a7lVSLdr1qU7AQk)

**EDIT**

Una compañera ha intentado esto para meter los datos en cadena y comparar para poder buscar a un usuario pero no funciona como deberia, a veces solo saca el primer nombre en lista y ya, en sus palabras

"Debería extraer las líneas del archivo y guardarlos en una cadena donde diferentes datos están separados por comas. En una segunda cadena va a ir guardando cada dato antes de la coma y comparándolo con la cadena que ingresa el usuario, en caso de que no coincida que recorra la coma y compare con el siguiente dato después de la coma, así hasta terminar la línea, con todas las líneas"

este es su codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i,j,l,x;
    char cad[120]={},bolet[10],name,otro[60]={},usuario[40]={};
    char boleta[30][10],nombre[30][50],ap[30][60],edad[30][2],correo[30].[60],grupo[30][4];
    /*Limpieza de arreglos*/
    for(i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<60;j++)
        {
            boleta[i][j]='\0';
            nombre[i][j]='\0';
            ap[i][j]='\0';
            edad[i][j]='\0';
            correo[i][j]='\0';
            grupo[i][j]='\0';
         }
    }
    /*El usuario ingresa lo que desea buscar y lo guarda en una cadena*/
    printf("Ingrese la boleta que desea buscar: ");
    gets(usuario);
    /*Se abre y lee el archivo*/
    FILE *archivo;
    archivo=fopen("archivodatos.csv","r");
    if(archivo!=NULL)
    {
        while (fscanf(archivo,"%[^\n]",cad)!=EOF)/*Extrae línea por línea y la guarda en una cadena*/
        {
            l=strlen(cad);
            for(i=0;i<l;i++)
            {
                if(cad[i]!=',')
                {
                    otro[x]=cad[i];
                    x++;
                    if(strcmp(otro,usuario)==0)
                    {
                        puts(cad);
                    }
                }
                if(cad[i]==',')
                {
                    x=0;
                    otro[x]=cad[i+1];
                    x++;
                    if(strcmp(otro,usuario)==0)
                    {
                        puts(cad);
                    }
                    if(strcmp(otro,usuario)!=0)
                    printf("Dato no encontrado");
                }
            }
        }

        }
}
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo tal y como has comentado... ¿has intentado algo de código para implementar dicho procedimiento? Básicamente has puesto el código que te hicieron ayer, poco a poco te van a hacer todas las tareas y no vas a aprender nada chiquillo...

Comment: ¿Por qué no intentas meter todos los datos en estructuras? Y para modificar solo cambias el valor dentro de la estructura.

Comment: Hola, perdon, he actualizado la pregunta con la idea de una compañera para guardar los datos en cadenas y buscarlos, el problema es que su programa tiene algun error que no detectamos y creo que en base a este programa podriamos acomodarlo para poder manipular la información a nuestro gusto, espero nos puedan ayudar :)

Comment: ¿No es válido utilizar `struct`s?

Comment: Exactamente ¿qué debe hacer el programa?. ¿leer los datos de un archivo con comas y luego _"modificar"_ el archivo sin comas?. ¿qué papel juega la búsqueda de los datos que presentó el código de tu amiga?